# Android: Sort JSON

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview

New to using REST API and JSON files, but I have retrieved data from a weather API about my current locations weather conditions. The JSON file has data, such as my location, weather speed etc. I wish to sort all these individual parts of data into textViews so they can be clearly seen.

My Asynch Class:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.widget.*;
import java.util.Date;
import android.util.Log;

public class RESTAPI extends Activity {

ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
// json test string
String jsonTest;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_restapi);
    // start the  AsyncTask for calling the REST service using httpConnect class
    new AsyncTaskParseJson().execute();
}


// added asynctask class methods below -  you can make this class as a separate class file
public class AsyncTaskParseJson extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    // set the url of the web service to call
    String yourServiceUrl = "http://api.apixu.com/v1/current.json?key=e87e62510df946cc84c02652162112&q=LN11RX";

    @Override

    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    @Override

    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        try {
            // create new instance of the httpConnect class
            httpConnect jParser = new httpConnect();

            // get json string from service url
            String json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(yourServiceUrl);

            // save returned json to your test string
            jsonTest = json.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String strFromDoInBg) {
        TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.jsontext);
        tv1.setText(jsonTest);
    }

}
```

}

My httpConnect Class to handle the URL:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import android.util.Log;


public class httpConnect {

final String TAG = "JsonParser.java";

static String json = "";

public String getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    try {

        URL u = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection restConnection = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
        restConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        restConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-length", "0");
        restConnection.setUseCaches(false);
        restConnection.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        restConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
        restConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
        restConnection.connect();
        int status = restConnection.getResponseCode();

        // switch statement to catch HTTP 200 and 201 errors
        switch (status) {
            case 200:
            case 201:

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(restConnection.getInputStream()));

                // create a new string builder to store json data returned from the REST service
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                // loop through returned data line by line and append to stringbuilder 'sb' variable
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line+"\n");
                }
                br.close();

                try {
                    json = sb.toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
                }
                return json;
        }
        // HTTP 200 and 201 error handling from switch statement
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Malformed URL ");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "IO Exception ");
    }
    return null;
}
```

So is there anyway to sort the returned data and put each bit of data into its own textbox?

Screenshot of JSON:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, try giving this [link](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/) a go.  Let me know if I have misunderstood and I will try and help you with an alternative.

Edit: 
Roughly another way to dynamically create new a new TextView and set data:

```
TextView view;
LinearLayout currLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout);
for(String value : items) {
    view = new TextView();
    view.setText(value);
    currLayout.addView(view);
}
```

Comment: So i already have the Json array that holds the Json objects, its called Json or as a string JsonTest and i want to loop through these to search for the objects such as location or name and then seperate it up into textviews

Comment: I think the best way might be to map it into a Java object such as `Location` which includes all of the variables/fields within your JSON String.  From this, you will have easier access to getter/setter methods which you can then just call `Location.getName()`, `Location.getRegion()` etc.

If you end up deciding to go this route, you can then use Gson (the link I provided) to map your JSON into the Location object.  An example might be as follows: `Location loc = gson.fromJson(jsonTest, Location.class);`

Answer (score 0):

- Make pojo classes for the response you get:

Open any converting site like this:-

http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

- here paste the json reponse, and click zip, all pojo class will be automatically created for you.

Now in your code do this

```
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        try {
            // create new instance of the httpConnect class
            httpConnect jParser = new httpConnect();

            // get json string from service url
            String json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(yourServiceUrl);

            // save returned json to your test string
            jsonTest = json.toString();
Gson gson = new Gson();
/*here Example class is the main pojo class, you can use this class which will be there in the zip, which is created from jsontoPojo converting site */

Example  response = gson.fromJson(json, Example.class);

/*
 *Now to get data 
 * just do this */

String name = getLocation().getName();
.
.
.


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

For details view this example,[example of data parsing using gson](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html)

And you need to add this dependency as well in build.gradle file

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
```